# Gulp is not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Faced with such a problem. Doesn't want to install gulp on the working computer. NodeJS is installed. These are the errors that come out:

```
1382 error code ENOENT
1383 error syscall lstat
1384 error path C:\Users\Maratkanov.IUS\AppData\Roaming\npm
1385 error errno -4058
1386 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Maratkanov.IUS\AppData\Roaming\npm'
1387 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1388 verbose exit -4058
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Tell me how is it treated? Win10 operating system

Comment: It's seems you didn't install npm

Comment: have you installed nodejs? try node -v on terminal

Comment: npm installed and nodejs installed
$ node -v
v15.0.1

$ npm -v
7.0.3